# Wordpress's functions.php won't detect site's language when i'm not logged in

Tags: php, wordpress, function, multiple-languages

I'm working in inbound marketing company and they use X theme.co theme.

the site has 2 languages hebrew and english.
I'm trying to make a shortcode to add the previous events using Ajax and Functions.php.
While I'm logged in the site know how to detect whether it's english or hebrew.
but when I'm logged out the site will give me the main language which is hebrew.
by the way there are hebrew events and english events ,it's not the same db.
and When you first go to events page it will detect the language but won't detect it after you click the "add more events" which will activate the function in functions.php

I don't know why its acting like that. please help!

```
function load_events_by_ajax_callback(){

check_ajax_referer('load_more_events','security');
$paged = $_POST['page'];

//Years
$prev_year=$_POST['cos_prev_year'];
$curr_year=$_POST['cos_curr_year'];
//Years

$all_events="";

global $post;

$args = array(

    'post_type'             => 'event',
    'meta_key'              => '_event_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page'        => '12',
    'paged'                 => $paged,

    'meta_query'            => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_event_date',
            'type'      => 'numeric',
        ),
    )

);

$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if( $featured_query->have_posts() ):           
    while( $featured_query->have_posts() ) : $featured_query->the_post();

        $date = get_field('_event_date');
        $get_the_date=date_parse_from_format("d.m.Y", $date);
        $display_date=$get_the_date["year"].'/'.$get_the_date["month"].'/'.$get_the_date["day"];
        $month=$get_the_date["month"];
        $month_name=date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));
        $img_url=get_the_post_thumbnail_url(null,'large');

        //Years
        $curr_year=$get_the_date["day"];
        $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('y',$curr_year);
        $curr_year=$dt->format('Y');

        if($curr_year != $prev_year){
             $all_events.='<h5 class="h-custom-headline cs-ta-center h5 accent"><span>'.$curr_year.'</span></h5>';
            $prev_year=$curr_year;

        }
        //Years

        $all_events.='<div class="novus_ptBMtYhoMB317wduyTDqor0Ys x-column x-sm cs-ta-center x-1-3" style="margin:1% !important; float:none !important; display:inline-block !important; vertical-align:top !important;" >';
        $all_events.='<div class="x-recent-posts cf horizontal">';
        $all_events.='<a class="x-recent-post1 with-image " href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">';
        $all_events.='<article class="event type-event status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry ">';
        $all_events.='<div class="entry-wrap">';
        //Start - date of the event
                if(time()>strtotime($date)){
                        $all_events.='<div style="background:rgba(128,128,128,0.7) !important;" class="shortcode_event_date">';
                        $all_events.='<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                            if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'he'){
                                $all_events.='<span class="title"> אירוע הסתיים </span>';
                            }

                            else if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'){
                                $all_events.='<span class="title"> Event ended </span>';
                            }
                        $all_events.='</div>';
                    }
                else{
                    $all_events.='<div style="background:rgba(37,206,190, 0.8) !important;" class="shortcode_event_date">';
                    $all_events.='<i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
                    $all_events.='<span class="date"> '.$display_date.' </span>';
                    $all_events.='</div>';
                }
        //End - date of the event
        $all_events.='<div class="x-recent-posts-img" style="background-image: url('.$img_url.');"> </div>';
        $all_events.='<div class="x-recent-posts-content">';
        $all_events.='<h3 class="h-recent-posts">'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
        $all_events.='</div>';
        $all_events.="</div>";
        $all_events.='</article>';
        $all_events.='</a>';
        $all_events.='</div>';
        $all_events.="</div>";

        endwhile;


    endif; wp_reset_query();

    //Years
    $all_events.='<script>';
    $all_events.='jQuery(document).ready(function($){';
    $all_events.='$("#curr-year").val("'.$curr_year.'");';
    $all_events.='$("#prev-year").val("'.$prev_year.'");';
    $all_events.='});';
    $all_events.='</script>';
    //Years

    echo $all_events;
    wp_die();
```

}

Comment: If the user is not logged in, how would it know what language to use for unknown user, except to use default language?

Comment: There is no need for users feature in this site. Its only informative site. the only user is the admin

Comment: Then how will WP know which language to detect?

Comment: Can we have the concerned part of your functions.php ?

Comment: BTW the ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE will echo 'he' when im not logged in and 'en' othewise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer here!
Enable Ajax filtering in WPML

https://wpml.org/forums/topic/string-translation-doesnt-work-for-not-logged-in-user-in-woocommerce-quick-view/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)